# C# How can I make a loop which changes 3 labels

Tags: c#, button, label

I am working on a project which has 3 labels and 3 buttons. ButtonBiezacy changes the labels that they show previous/current/next day of the week. How can I make that the buttonPoprzedni will be changing all 3 labels properly (so If I click buttonPoprzedni once it will change labelWczoraj from "wczoraj: piątek" into "wczoraj: czwartek" etc. and for each click it will be changing)?

Is using the switch in this situation was a good idea?

```
public string NazwaDnia(int zmienna)
{
    switch (zmienna)
    {
        case 1:
            return "poniedziałek";

        case 2:
            return "wtorek";

        case 3:
            return "środa";

        case 4:
            return "czwartek";

        case 5:
            return "piątek";

        case 6:
            return "sobota";

        case 7:
            return "niedziela";

        default:
            return "";

    }
}

private void updateLabelWczoraj()
{
    DateTime Dzisiaj = DateTime.Now;
    int NumerDnia = (int)Dzisiaj.DayOfWeek;
    labelWczoraj.Text = "wczoraj: " + NazwaDnia(NumerDnia - 1);
}

private void updateLabelDzisiaj()
{
    DateTime Dzisiaj = DateTime.Now;
    int NumerDnia = (int)Dzisiaj.DayOfWeek;
    labelDzisiaj.Text = "dzisiaj: " + NazwaDnia(NumerDnia);
}

private void updateLabelJutro()
{
    DateTime Dzisiaj = DateTime.Now;
    int NumerDnia = (int)Dzisiaj.DayOfWeek;
    labelJutro.Text = "jutro: " + NazwaDnia(NumerDnia + 1);
}

private void buttonBieżący_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonPoprzedni.Enabled = true;
    buttonNastępny.Enabled = true;
    updateLabelWczoraj();
    updateLabelDzisiaj();
    updateLabelJutro();
}

private void buttonPoprzedni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void buttonNastępny_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this

```
     Dictionary<int, string> daysDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
                                                {
                                                   {1, "poniedziałek"},
                                                   {2, "wtorek"},
                                                   {3, "środa"},
                                                   {4, "czwartek"},
                                                   {5, "piątek"},
                                                   {6, "sobota"},
                                                   {7, "niedziela"}
                                                };
     return daysDictionary[zmienna];
```

You could also make the dictionary a static field on your class so it doesn't get created every time you click the button (although performance probably won't really be an issue).

You could also put the whole Dictionary declaration on one line, but I think it is more readable this way.

Comment: NOTE: this doesn't have any error checking, so if you expect to pass numbers like 0 or 8 and get a blank string, you could get an exception with this method.  So you'd have to check inputs if that is the case.